# Eclipse Call hierarchy showing wrong hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse

Call hierarchy showing called methods in method itself instead of method who called that method:

```
public class DummyClass {

    public void test1(){
        test2();
    }

    public void test2(){
        test3();
    }

    public void test3(){
        test4();
    }

    public void test4(){
        test1();
    }

}
```

[image: Eclipse Testing Image]

Comment: This works correctly on my Eclipse which I just copy-pasted into. Rebuild and clean your project then try again.

Comment: Fixed up code formatting and added alt text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you selected `Callee Hierarchy` instead of `Caller Hierarchy`:

- Callee Hierarchy

  [image: Callee]
- Caller Hierarchy

  [image: Caller]